# Firefox: Is it possible to disable exit alerts?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firefox, javascript

Sometimes the website will show an alert box akin to "Are you sure you want to leave?" when you try to leave the site.

Is it possible to disable this from happening, without using something like the NoScript extension?

Answer (score 2):

**Tools > Page Info [Permissions]** will let you set the permissions for a particular page/site.

On the **Open Pop-up Windows** setting, clear the "Use Default" check-box, and set **Block**

If that's not enough, you may be able to use a GreaseMonkey script, but without knowing which web-site, no-one here will be able to tell you how.

Answer (score 1):

Not limited to Firefox, with **[ClickOff](http://www.johanneshuebner.com/en/clickoff.shtml)** you can get rid of **any** annoying popup, on a Windows system.

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu

Comment: ahh, sorry you should add this bit of information to your question :)

Comment: My mistake. I added it as tags but not in the post itself.

Comment: @Rajje - no, you didn't ... twas me editing the tags for you. :) Anyway, i'll leave the answer there in case someone stumbles over this question.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is really late, but this question showed up in Google for me when I was looking for a solution to this problem today.  The solution I eventually found is here: http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/23865

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           BlockUnloadEvents
// @namespace      http://theaceoffire.8k.com/STOPTHEMADDNESS
// @description    This stops ANY AND ALL javascript that stops you from leaving a page. Inspired by this greasemonky script: http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/20781
// @include        *
// ==/UserScript==
(function() {
      unsafeWindow.onbeforeunload = null;

      unsafeWindow.onunload = null;

      //unsafeWindow.alert = null;

      //unsafeWindow.confirm = null;

      //unsafeWindow.prompt = null;

      //unsafeWindow.open = null;  
})();
```